# Get the height of a widget in a List

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painter

I'm working on a `CustomPainter` widget that receives a `List<Widget>` as an argument.
I would like to know the size of each of my `Widget` so I can adjust my paint.
The `List<Widget>` will be a user-selected `List` so I can't use `GlobalKeys` here.

I watched some answers on StackOverflow and articles on the subject but every time the answer seems not adapted to my problem.

```dart
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Widget> myWidgetList;

  MyPainter({
    this.myWidgetList,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    for (var item in myWidgetList) {
      // print my widget height.
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Are widgets inside the list the same height?

Comment: @ArturSikora not necessarily, that's why I need to adjust my CustomPainter depending on the `List<Widget>`

Comment: I think each widget need to be render to get the size no?

Comment: @mariofrancois yeah I agree. Pretty sure you have to wait for the layout phase to complete to find the height of a widget. But if you pass a specific height parameter to each widget then you could just use that

Comment: As others have said, you can only get the height of a widget after the layout phase. Consider a `Container()` in your widget list - what is its height? It's impossible to know, as its height depends on the constraints available and its child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't get the size of my widget before the rendering, I wrapped every widget in my `List<Widget>` into another widget that will use `GlobalKey` and then get access to the size of each of my widget with `Context`.

It's not a perfect solution but it's the best I could find so far.

```dart
class SubtaskWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function onChange;
  final SubTasksViewModel model;

  SubtaskWrapper({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChange,
    required this.model,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(postFrameCallback);

    return Container(
      key: widgetKey,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  GlobalKey widgetKey = GlobalKey();
  Size? oldSize;

  void postFrameCallback(_) {
    BuildContext? context = widgetKey.currentContext;
    if (context == null) return;

    Size? newSize = context.size;
    if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    oldSize = newSize;
    onChange(newSize, model);
  }
}
```